# C# Abstraction/Reflection and DbSet<T>

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core

I am setting up a Net Core page that uses several DbSets as a hook for a set of SQL tables (each table has a unique class name). Each class inherits from a general class I wrote - when the class is instantiated, only variables inside the general class are set - the derived classes are mainly for structure and are used later. Please see the example code below:

```
public class GeneralSet
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   public string set { get; set; }
   public string userID { get; set; }
}

public class SpecificSetOne : GeneralSet
{
    public SpecificSetOne(string _set, string _userID) : base(_set, _userID)
    {
    }
    public string otherVariableUsedLater {get; set;}
}

public class SpecificSetTwo : GeneralSet
{
    public SpecificSetTwo(string _set, string _userID) : base(_set, _userID)
    {
    }
    public string otherVariableUsedLaterWithDifferentName {get; set;}
}
```

I have my DbContext set up as follows:

```
public class SetDbContext : DbContext
{
   public SetDbContext(DbContextOptions<SetDbContext> options) :
      base(options)
   {
   }

   public DbSet<SpecificSetOne> SetOneData { get; set; }
   public DbSet<SpecificSetTwo> SetTwoData { get; set; }
 }
```

My controllers see a string variable "set" sent via url.

I am currently writing a repository to control CRUD functionality for the tables. I am trying to contain it all within one repository and to call the appropriate CRUD functionality for a specific set based on which set string is passed in via that url. Is this possible in c#? I've been reviewing reflection but am not exactly sure if what I want is doable or advisable.

Thank you very much, hopefully this is somewhat clear.

Comment: Containing multiple DataSet<T> inside a DbContext is exactly what the DbContext is meant for. So in order to use 1 set for a request, you just inject the _dbContext in your controller, and in the controller's constructor, based on the query string you can do `_dbSet = _dbContext.SetOneDate` or `_dbContext.SetTwoData` and then just use the `_dbSet` in your methods. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for getting back to me. The problem is that inside each CRUD method, I need to create a new instance of the class for that set. For for example, if I do _dbSet = _dbContext.SetOneData; when I want to do _dbSet.Add(), I'll need to add a new SetOneData object. This is where I'm stuck. Same thing for CRUD method return types - should I just write a set of CRUD methods for each DbSet or is there a way to do it once and abstract the rest away? Thanks!

Comment: That's solved through generics and an interface. I suggest you go read more about those two! They are very helpful in your case.

Comment: Thanks, will do! Any specific code examples you recommend checking out that could apply? Appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you detail the schema of database? Do you have 1 table?

Comment: What version of Entity Framework do you use?